# Hyperthreading (smt) set to 'notsupported' on i7-10875H 8/16 processor running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cpu

My simple question is why?

| Specs for i7-10875H |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Num of Cores** | 8 |
| **Num of Threads** | 16 |

BIOS hyperthreading enabled

```
$ lscpu | grep -e Socket -e Core -e Thread  
Thread(s) per core:              1  
Core(s) per socket:              8  
Socket(s):                       1  
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10875H CPU @ 2.30GHz  

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control  
notsupported  

$ lsb_release -a  
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS  
Release:    20.04  
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Take a look at your `/etc/default/grub` file and look at the flags set for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. If you see `nosmt`, then that would be the culprit.

Comment: Also check BIOS settings, as it can usually be disabled there.

Comment: I've checked both. Grub does not disable. Definitely enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Any other grub kernel line options in use, like noacpi?  That can kill multithreading too.